# C# Serialize Object instance to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I got a little problem with serializing object instance and let some pseudo code speak for itself:

```
List<A> ListOfA = new List<A>();

[Serializable]
public class A
{
public Object Instance;
...
}

[Serializable]
public class B
{
    public String SomeAttribute = "example"; 
}

// This will be called:

void Serialize()
{
    var a = new A();
    a.Instance = new B();
    ListOfA.Add(a);

 // a.Instance = new String("test"); works but List<String>, B, ... throws Invalid Operation Exception when serializing:

    using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ListOfA.GetType());
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, ListOfA );
    }
}
```

Anyone have a solution for this?

I have tried to use `XmlInclude` without any result.

Is it even possible to serialize Object without knowing its type?

Comment: What error do you get during serialization? (look for the inner exception(s))

Comment: Error was The type ... B was not excepted. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically. How ever I find solution for my problem and I wrote it down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for your fast response but I did find solution for my problem by giving second parameter to XmlSerializer:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ListOfA.GetType(), new Type[] { typeof(B) });
```

And this way I don't have to add [XmlInclude(typeof(B))] to class A...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(B))]
public class A {
  public Object Instance;
}
```

Btw. [Serializable] is useless for xml serialization.